# Why does TextToSpeech fail to initialize in this class?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a class which is supposed to speak the description of a given entry from glossary. The code is like this:

```
package college.projects.glossary;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;

public class GlossaryEntryPlayer extends Object implements IGlossaryEntryPlayer, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    protected MyActivity activity_;

    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech_ = null;

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = textToSpeech_.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                MyUtils.UIDebug(this.activity_.getApplicationContext(), "Language support is bad");
            } else {
                MyUtils.UIDebug(this.activity_.getApplicationContext(), "Language support is OK");
            }
        } else {
            MyUtils.UIDebug(this.activity_.getApplicationContext(), "TextToSpeech is bad");
        }
    }

    public GlossaryEntryPlayer(MyActivity activity) {
        super();
        this.activity_ = activity;
        textToSpeech_ = new TextToSpeech(this.activity_, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean play(GlossaryEntry entry) {
        if (null != entry) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                textToSpeech_.speak(entry.getDescription(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                return true;
            } else {
                MyUtils.UIDebug(this.activity_.getApplicationContext(), "Version is bad");
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is in `onInit()` since I always get the message *"TextToSpeech is bad"*. What's wrong with this class? Android emulator used is 5.1 WVGA API 30, RAM 512 MB, the default language is US-ENG. The laptop on which Android Studio runs is Lenovo AMD A4-G50, 4GB Ram, 1.8Ghz

Comment: Probably the error is TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA in which case you have to start an intent to send the user to the app store to download the missing data.

Comment: The tts is not initializing for some reason. :)

Comment: You're doing some very unusual things with regards to the activity reference.  Either that is the culprit or the tts is simply not initializing because it's not installed.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Google](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech), "*Apps targeting Android 11 that use text-to-speech should declare `TextToSpeech.Engine#INTENT_ACTION_TTS_SERVICE` in the queries elements of their manifest:*"

So, add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Adding this before `<application` tag worked for me. (Android Studio says Element queries is not allowed here though).